# SessionStateStoreProvider implementation using Ignite thin client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ignite, thin-client, session-state-provider

We are attempting to use Apache Ignite as a distributed storage for session variables in a web farm environment. I know that Apache Ignite already has a thick client session state provider in nuget but it is too heavy and too complex for our current requirements. I just need to be able to use the session variables in the front end in a web farm environment.

I couldn't see much examples of implementations for `SessionStateStoreProviderBase` class. I'm not sure if all methods need to be overridden or if it is fine to just override specific ones. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Ignite's own implementation and work from that:

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/Apache.Ignite.AspNet/IgniteSessionStateStoreProvider.cs